# If I put 12 volts across a 1 ohm resistor, will it pull 144 watts?

Tags: ohms-law, ohms

I would think putting 12 volts across a 1 ohm resistor would pull 12 amps of current, and since watts=volts*amps the resistor would be dissipating 144 watts of heat,  all of this assuming the source could supply it.  Am I correct?

Comment: And you had a 150 Watt (or more) resistor...

Comment: ... with a pretty small tempco...

Comment: So this leads on to the question,  How would I get 4 amps from a 12 volt PSU without needing a 150 watt resistor.

Comment: @Rhezner  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I had my full question in another post that wasn't phrased very well.  I want to limit the current going into a circuit (step up converter) to 4 amps from a computer power supply,  but I cant just put a resistor in series with the circuit because it will just blow up.  I was using a 220 ohm resistor before to mess around with 30 volts at about 50 milli-amps from my boost converter but I want a bit more current (4 amps).

Comment: Why do you want to limit the current?  The present version of the question is still not clear, by the way.

Comment: I want to limit the current because it will fry my boost converter or blow the fuse if I dont.

Comment: @Rhezner what are you trying to connect that will pull 4 amps? Just ***Don't*** short out the connection and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Rhezner shorting a power supply is pretty much always always always bad. If you need that type of protection, replace the fuse with a 4 amp one. It's a common car fuse (ATC or ATM size I believe) If you pull more than 4 amps, the fuse blows before the module burns itself out.

Comment: but thats exactly what I want to do with it is short the connection,  Im not doing this for a practical purpose,  I want to mess around with it and create sparks and short pins on an old CPU(don't ask).

Comment: @Rhezner if you want to make it into a stun gun/zapper, a normal boost module like this is the wrong way to go...

Comment: Do you know photonicinduction on youtube?  he melts metal by shorting out 2 leads onto it,  I want to do that but on a smaller scale (4 amps),  is it possible with my boost converter?  Thanks for your help(and patience)!

Comment: Please update your question with the extra information explaining what you are trying to do. The question as it is currently written either appears to be a duplicate, or too vague, and will be closed.

Comment: @Rhezner he uses huge transformers for raw power, high current melting, not small switching regulators. You really can't scale this down.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct assuming an ideal 12V source and an ideal resistor.

They will be reasonablly accurate using a power resistor of appropriate power rating and a reasonablly well regulated 12V source of appropriate current rating.

If you try it with a normal 1/4W or so resistor the thing will almost certainly go up in smoke. At that point it's anyones guess what will happen to the resistance, maybe it will go down as a result of carbonisation of the insulation, maybe it will go up as a result of burning away the conductor, you just don't known.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct.

Typically resistors of this power will be wirewound. When choosing the device make sure to read the data sheet and figure out what temperature the case will reach at this power and what ventilation the datasheet is assuming.

The wire will usually have a positive temperature coefficient so the resistance will increase with temperature. Again, the datasheet should show this information.

Comment: I am wondering how I would get a 4 amp current from a 12 volt computer PSU without a big resistor that could just take the heat.

Comment: Modify your question and explain what you are trying to do.